# Getting mouse events from a View in the Parent ViewController

Tags: objective-c, delegates, mouseevent

I need to understanding how to get the mouse events from a View in the Parent view Controller.

Lets say I have a view controller, and among many things It manages an NSMutableArray of points.  I can initialize the array and pass it to the view class where it will draw to the
rect of the view.

If I have configured some typical mouse events in the view, I could add points in the view
and have them also draw.

What I don't understand is how to send that information back to the parent view controller so it can add the point to the point array.

I'm not sure if I am supposed to some how overload the methods(they do not respond in a controller)  or if I can set up a delegate(Which I don't know exactly how to do for this).

Advice is greatly appreciated, and an example would be great too.

FYI this was a simple example of a more complex problem I need to solve, but the solution would still apply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie to Cocoa, Using custom delegate is still foreign to me, but that is the solution. Good old object message passing.

1 Create a delegate in your view class -->    id mouseDelagate.

2 Create a simple protocol class with at least one method.

3 in the actual mouse event method in the view class. call the protocol method with
the delegate [mouseDelegate mouseDidMove: point ].(however you defined the method).

4 set the delegate in the view controller class in the awakeFromNib file([viewClass setMouseDelegate: self]);

5 implement the protocol method;

```
 -(void)MouseDidMove{

 NSLog(@"moving");

 }
```

6 remember to import the protocol in both classes